# How does python sum of a 2d array return a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum

I came across a piece of python code where the sum function of a 2d array evaluates to a list.

For example:

`a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]]`

`sum(a,[])` returns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']`

Why does this happen? Maybe I'm missing something basic, but would like to understand the mechanics of this.

Comment: Sum adds the components of what you put in it. The array you have is a list of 3 lists so when you use the sum function it combines those 3 lists.

Comment: Ethan - @Nick's answer (accepted answer) of initializing the sum with an empty array, [], in this case was the key to clarify it for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`sum(iterable, /, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#sum):

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total

So for your code, the operation produced by `sum` is

```
[] + ['a','b','c'] + ['d','e','f'] + ['g','h','i']
```

which is a list concatenation, and produces:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Note that if you don't supply the `start` value of `[]`, sum uses the default `start` value of `0` and performs:

```
0 + ['a','b','c'] + ['d','e','f'] + ['g','h','i']
```

which results in a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: Thank you, @Nick. This explanation helps.

Comment: @Nrupesh no worries - I'm glad it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you Can Understand It Simply Like Here

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
```

It is Doing It as Follows :

```
result = []
for list in a:
    result += list
```

And Now returning The Result List :

```
print(result)
```

I Also Informs you That That Above method Is Fast From sum(a, []) Method

Sum Function Does not Works Like That But You Can Understand Easily By This That How It Works

Comment: Sorry, Kartikey, this explanation didn't help. Please check out @Nick's explanation that I accepted as the answer.